# SQL Query Where Array is in Array Field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table which has an array field called `countries` So lets say for example in this table called `country_list` i have the following records

```
Name         Countries
Asia         ['Malaysia, Singapore, Hong Kong]
Worldwide    ['Malaysia, Singapore, Hong Kong, Croatia, USA]
```

Now if i want to query this table to find out which records have `['Malaysia, 'Singapore']`, how do i write the query in my ruby console.

I tried to do this but it didnt work

`CountryList.where("countries IN (['Malaysia', 'Singapore'])")` 
but it didnt work as expected.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This a curious approach. I wonder why you didn't make `Country` and `Region` and associate them. Life would be somewhat easier.

Comment: @jvillian because i am getting my list of regions and countries from the ISO3166 global configuration and each of those records is tied to a company so meaning there is a company id field for each of those records. Making a Country and Region table will require manual entry of records into these table which i feel is nt necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
countries = ['Malaysia', 'Singapore']
query = CountryList.where(":name = ANY(country_list.countries)", name: countries[0])

countries[1..-1].each do |c|
  query = query.or(CountryList.where(":name = ANY(country_list.countries)", name: c))
 end
query
```

Have Checked its working

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer. In order to find out if a value is contained in a `postgres` array column you must search all the values in the array using `value = ANY(column)`. This means that if you want to search for multiple values you will need need to search them independently using `OR`. If you wanted to make sure that both Malaysia and Singapore existed you could use `AND` instead via  `query = query.where(":name = ANY(country_list.countries)", name: c)` inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct approach to query serialized data. But the other work around is by selecting/filtering from all the results. Eg:

> Model.all.select{|s| (s.countries &['Malaysia',
>   'Singapore']).present?}